Where to place the poles on a map of the Earth, where polar circles are not straight lines?
Consider this question, that was part of an evaluation that my daughter had in school:

The underlined question translates to "draw a green dot at the north pole and the south pole".
I think that the answer my daughter gave is correct, however the teacher marked it as incorrect, but I have a hard time formulating exactly why.
I don't have the answer the teacher considers correct, but I think she expected the students to draw the points representing the poles at the very top and bottom of the Earth, on the line.
My question boils down to this: considering the polar circles are not straight lines, shouldn't the poles be (approximately) where my daughter drew them?

This seems more like an [earthscience.se] question, but I expect the teacher wanted the poles marked at the poles (+/- 90°), not on the Arctic/Antarctic Circles (~+/-66.5°).

Not necessarily. It depends on the projection. For example this projection has  curved lines of latitude (arctic circle, tropics etc) but the poles are at the extreme points top and bottom:
 (via https://map-projections.net/single-view/azimuthal-equidistant-hemi:flat-stf)
If the poles were at the green dots then this map would be showing more than half of the earth, and that's fairly uncommon for this sort of projection that is usually two halves showing separate hemispheres.
Impossible to say for sure without knowing the precise projection used in the exercise map, but it looks so close to the one I've linked to that I think it probably is that projection. I can't actually find a hemispherical or near-hemispherical projection where both poles are not at the extreme points...
At least she is learning that the earth isn't flat!

Did some flat-earther do a drive-by downvote? What's wrong with my answer?

The problem seems to be a misunderstanding of the definitions of "polar circle" and "pole" on the part of both child and parent. The former delineating the regions with only one day per year due to axial tilt, and the latter being the center of that region, along the axis upon which Earth spins. Breaking this into a projection issue seems a forest/trees problem.
